# Positioning item to the left inside Table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, positioning, itemize

I am facing a problem that the item is positioned on the center of the table column, may i know how to make it to be positioned on the left side of the column? This is the problem i am facing. [image]

This is the code i am using.

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you actually pasted your code so that it's easily copied.  Also, we can give much better answers if you provide a fully functioning MWE (preamble and all).

Answer (score 2):

If you want the entry of a column to be positioned left, you may use `l` in the description of columns, e.g. `\begin{tabular}{|l|l|c|}`. Then you obtain exceptions, using `multicolumn`, e.g. `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Types}`.

BTW: MWE instead of a picture will be much more useful.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a combination of `tabularx` and `enumitem` packages.

`tabularx` provides `X` column parameters which create an expandable column which is treated as a column of type `p{<width>}` where `<width>` is the greatest value such that the entire width of the column is that passed to `tabularx`.  Technically the `minipage` nested within the `X`-type column is a bit of overkill.  But, it does give a bit better control over the horizontal alignment.

`enumitem` allows you to more readily control the various parameters shaping the list.  In this MWE here, I've indicated that the left margin should be set to `1em`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|c|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Classification of the critical point $(0,0)$ of $x'=Ax$, $\mathbf{|A|} \ne 0$}
  \\\hline
  \centering Types & \centering Type of Critical Point & Stability \\\hline
  1. Real unequal eigenvalues of the same sign && \\
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em]
      \item \lipsum[1]
    \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}
  &
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em]
    \item \lipsum[1]
    \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}
  &
  Unstable
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

You've left out the preamble to your MWE so I had to guess a bit at the packages you might be using.

[image]