# Text isn't correct in the longtable

Tags: longtable

Good evening

The green text in the 3rd row in 3rd column is text what I want to change. The problem is with size - the text is on the right side and on the left side is a free space. I want to use all space as the red text in the 1st row in the 3rd column (picture below). How to do it?

Thanks for help.

```
    \documentclass[10pt,a6paper]{book}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[main=english,slovak]{babel}
    \usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
    \usepackage[a6paper, top=10mm, left=10mm, right=10mm, bottom=10mm,foot=5mm,marginparsep=0mm,showframe]{geometry}
    %showframe
    \usepackage{tipa}
    \usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{lscape}

    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}

    {\small
    \begin{longtable}{|l|p{2cm}|p{3cm}|}
      \hline
      {\color{red} some text}           & {\color{red} some text}         & \foreignlanguage{slovak}{{\color{red} - some long text some long text some long text some long text}}\\
                                        &                                 & \foreignlanguage{slovak}{{\color{red} - some long text some long text some long text some long text}}\\
      {\color{Brown} some text}         & {\color{Brown} some text}       & \foreignlanguage{slovak}{{\color{Brown} - some long text some long text some long text some long text}}\\ 
      {\color{ForestGreen} some}        & {\color{ForestGreen} some text} & \setlist{nosep,topsep=0sp,label=--}
                                                                            \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                                                                            \begin{itemize}
                                                                              \item[-] \foreignlanguage{slovak}{{\color{ForestGreen} some long text some long text some long text some long text}}
                                                                              \item[-] \foreignlanguage{slovak}{{\color{ForestGreen} some long text some long text some long text some long text}}
                                                                            \end{itemize}\\  
  \hline                                                                
\end{longtable}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The green text is different because it's in an `itemize`, so the issue is with `itemize` indenting, not `longtable` as I see - is that right? This question may offer a solution http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91124/itemize-removing-natural-indent

Comment: You may also like to take a look at how to build an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) while it's great that you've included one, there are a lot of packages irrelevant to this problem which you could remove for conciseness (`graphicx`, `mathtools`,`fullpage` etc.).

Comment: add the option `wide=0pt` to itemize. Why do you replace the `dendash` with a `hyphen dash`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want one of these?

```
 \documentclass[10pt,a6paper]{book}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[main=english,slovak]{babel}
    \usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
    \usepackage[a6paper, margin=10mm, foot=5mm, marginparsep=0mm,showframe]{geometry}
    %showframe
    \usepackage{tipa}
    \usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{lscape}

    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}

    {\small\setlist[itemize]{nosep, ,label=--, wide = 0pt, before=\color{ForestGreen}}
    \begin{longtable}{|l|p{2cm}|p{3cm}|}
      \hline
      {\color{red} some text} & {\color{red} some text} & \foreignlanguage{slovak}{{\color{red} - some long text some long text some long text some long text}}\\
      & & \foreignlanguage{slovak}{{\color{red} - some long text some long text some long text some long text}}\\
      {\color{Brown} some text} & {\color{Brown} some text} & \foreignlanguage{slovak}{{\color{Brown} - some long text some long text some long text some long text}}\\
      {\color{ForestGreen} some} & {\color{ForestGreen} some text} &
      \vspace{-\baselineskip}
      \begin{itemize}
      \item \foreignlanguage{slovak}{some long text some long text some long text some long text}
      \item \foreignlanguage{slovak}{some long text some long text some long text some long text}
      \end{itemize}\\
  \hline
\end{longtable}}
\newpage
    {\small\setlist[itemize]{nosep , label=--, wide = 0pt, labelsep=.25em, leftmargin=*, before=\color{ForestGreen}}
    \begin{longtable}{|l|p{2cm}|p{3cm}|}
      \hline
      {\color{red} some text} & {\color{red} some text} & \foreignlanguage{slovak}{{\color{red} - some long text some long text some long text some long text}}\\
      & & \foreignlanguage{slovak}{{\color{red} - some long text some long text some long text some long text}}\\
      {\color{Brown} some text} & {\color{Brown} some text} & \foreignlanguage{slovak}{{\color{Brown} - some long text some long text some long text some long text}}\\
      {\color{ForestGreen} some} & {\color{ForestGreen} some text} &
      \vspace{-\baselineskip}
      \begin{itemize}
      \item \foreignlanguage{slovak}{some long text some long text some long text some long text}
      \item \foreignlanguage{slovak}{some long text some long text some long text some long text}
      \end{itemize}\\
  \hline
\end{longtable}}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer of A. Ellett in [Positioning item to the left inside Table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150641/positioning-item-to-the-left-inside-table/150653#150653) set leftmargin in itemize. I tried 1em and 0.5em for your problem and it looked fine. (0.5em gives better use of space. 1em alignes the text better with not-itemized cells in the rest of the column.)